# How to automatically generate methods like ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I want to create a custom class that extends uiviewcontroller with a function that when I create a subClass of my custom class, that function generate automatically. like viewDidLoad and didReceiveMemoryWarning in  subclasses of UIViewController.
what can I do?

My CustomViewController :

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController
```

My subclass of CustomViewController :

```
class MySubClass: CustomViewController {

   override func generatedFunction() {

       //Do something
   }
}
```

Comment: You can [create your own snippets](http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/).

Comment: These are life cycle methods of the view controller. if you not override this  will  call parent view controller means UIVIewController methods. you can't generate method like  viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use code snippets.
- Go to `/Applications/Xcode/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates` and edit the templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CustomViewController and then add your method to it and then call the method in the viewDidLoad. Like this

```
import UIKit

class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.generatedFunction()
    }

    public func generatedFunction() {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: CustomViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func generatedFunction() {
        super.generatedFunction()

        // Do Something
    }
}
```

You need to make sure that if you override `viewDidLoad`, then you need to call `super.viewDidLoad()` in it.