# How to create an override func like viewDidLoad?

Tags: swift

I'm just wondering how can I create a func like viewDidLoad that is always present when I create class that is a subclass of a UIViewController. So I created a class name SnapKitView. Then what I want to achieve is everytime I created a class that is a sub class of SnapKitView my `override awakeFromCode` func is always present.

eg:

```
class AuthView: SnapkitView {

     //this override func must be always present
     override func awakeFromCode() {

     }     

}
```

What I want to achieve is every time I subclass SnapKitView, `override awakeFromCode` is already prepopulated like `override viewDidLoad`. Is that possible?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to redefine `awakeFromCode` in each subclass, or do you just want each subclass to call the `awakeFromCode` defined in the parent?

Comment: @WillB I want awakeFromCode in each subclass.

Comment: Create a `protocol` with `awakeFromCode() ` instead .

Comment: So you want a kind of template that automatically create some method when you create a file?

Answer (score 1):

In the parent class, in this case `SnapKitView`, define the function normally like so

```
func awakeFromCode() {
    // Put any functionality here that applies to ALL subclasses
}
```

Then in each subclass, such as `AuthView`, override the function using the same function signature (same name and parameters, if any)

```
override awakeFromCode() {
    // This will call the original parent function and execute anything in its function body
    super.awakeFromCode()

    // Then do anything you want this subclass in particular to do here
}
```

`super.awakeFromCode()` will call the parent's implementation of that function, and you can put that either before, after, or in between the added subclass functionality depending on what order you want it to execute.

EDIT: Also, if one of your subclasses does not need to add any functionality beyond what the parent function does, you can just call the parent function in the subclass normally like `awakeFromCode()` without referencing `super`. You only need to reference `super` if you override it and want to call only the parent function and not the subclass's.

You may be interested in `required` function inheritance, which you can read more about here: [What does the "required" keyword in Swift mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26923123/1500134)

Comment: What I want to achieve is every time I subclass SnapKitView, `override awakeFromCode` is already prepopulated like `override viewDidLoad`. Is that possible?

Comment: @AlvinJohn Not feasibly, no. When Xcode automatically generates the `override viewDidLoad` function it's just making the shell of the function with an empty body. Until you add something to that shell it doesn't do anything, because it just calls the parent's `viewDidLoad` and then is done.

Comment: @AlvinJohn I should also mention `required` inheritance, which may be closer to what you want. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26923123/1500134

Comment: Is there's a way to tell xcode to automatically generate override 'func awakeFromCode' shell whenever `SnapKitView` is SubClass?

Comment: @AlvinJohn I've never tried it but according to this you can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40140247/1500134